# I have a small problem with engine.runAndWait()

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I have a program that's detects and recognizes faces, but thats not the point , while im trying to include "voice follower".

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

It is actually does saying and then after a few seconds the whole program is just crashes.
Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add tracebacks, it will help for solving a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate + 1)
engine.setProperty('voice', 'com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex')
engine.say(voice)

engine.runAndWait()
```

Please let me know if it works. If it doesn't also let me know.